# Vue3 <PropType> vs regular type annotation on defineProps

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

According to the vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#complex-prop-types)

> With type-based declaration, a prop can use a complex type much like any other type:

and the following example is given:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Book {
  title: string
  author: string
  year: number
}

const props = defineProps<{
  book: Book
}>()
</script>
```

The docs then state:

> For runtime declaration, we can use the PropType utility type:
>
> ```js
> import type { PropType } from 'vue'
>
> const props = defineProps({
>   book: Object as PropType<Book>
> })
> ```

What is meant here with runtime declaration? Typescript is a static type checker that catches errors at compile time. What would be one reason to use one approach over the other?

Comment: It looks like Vue is running an intermediate custom compiler step which synthesizes certain runtime checks from the TS Source before all of its types are erased. `PropType` is probably a marker type guiding the synthesis. This seems really nasty to me.